# Select Statement that orders depending on existence of foreign key in other table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables `a` and `b` where `b` contains a foreign key `fk_a_id` to table `a` id column.

Now I would like to select on table `a` but order the result depending on whether table `b` has a foreign key entry for it or not. the rows where table `b` does not have an entry for it should come first.

I haven't tried much yet, besides a join, which is probably not even the right direction.

```
select a.* 
from a as a
join b as b on b.fk_a_id = a.id
order by id desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a `left join`.  But that could duplicate rows if `b` contains multiple instances of a given key.

Another method uses logic in the `order by`:

```
select a.* 
from a
order by (case when not exists (select 1 from b where b.fk_a_id = a.id) then 1 else 2 end),
          id desc;
```

For performance, you would want an index on `b(fk_a_id)`.